# VS2013, TFS 2012 AutomatedTest NUnit not working problems

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I using VS2013. Test Framework is NUnit 2.6.4, NUnitTestAdapter is 1.2 Version. I local using ReSharper and all test successfully. But,this exception.

> TF900546: An unexpected error occurred while running the RunTests
>   activity: 'Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Client.ITestExecutorLauncher2'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio 2013 dll's have version number 12.0 and you are loading Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel version 11.0.0. This is the version that ships with VS2012. 
The 2013 version of this dll can be found in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow

Comment: I'm not very familiar with NUnit and it's testadapters but what I can found about it, is that it should be able to work with VS2013. So it seems that something went wrong with your configuration. 
You can try to re-install the test-adapter for VS2013, so it should be using the 2013 dll's.   
If that's not working, can you provide more information about the updates you have installed for Visual Studio (update 4, or another)?

edit: On the Nuget package for the Test Adapter they are stating that it is compatible with NUnit 2.0 through 2.6.3. Version 2.6.4 is not mentioned: http://bit.ly/1ySizJ8

Comment: I upgrade TFS 2013. My problem is fixed.