# Issue with NUnit and TFS Build 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, tfs, nunit, tfsbuild

I'm having an issue getting my build server to run my unit test suite. Here's the details:

- We're using NUnit 2.6.4
- The build server is running TFS Build 2012 with Update 4
- The TFS server is running TFS 2013 with Update 2
- I have my build controller set up to point to a version controlled folder that has 3rd party dependencies - in this folder are the 4 NUnit dependencies need to run NUnit tests on the build server.
- The Test Runner is setup properly to use Visual Studio's test runner
- Both Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4 are installed on the build server

When I check-in via a gated checkin through my build definition, I get this error:

TF900546: An unexpected error occurred while running the RunTests activity: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Client.**ITestExecutorLauncher2**' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel, **Version=11.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'.

This is the same problem found at:

[VS2013, TFS 2012 AutomatedTest NUnit not working problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000370/vs2013-tfs-2012-automatedtest-nunit-not-working-problems)

I'm using NUnit's latest Test Adapter found at: 
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d

When I decompile this assembly I see that adapter has a dependency on Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel version 11.00.

What is interesting here is looking through Client namespace of that class, there is no ITestExecutorLauncher2 which is what the run tests activity is looking for (I think).  However, ITestExecutorLauncher2 is found in version 12.00 of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.

My question is am do I have something misconfigured here or should NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter, Version=2.0.0.0 reference version 12.00 of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel and not version 11.00?

Fyi, I'm using the same Test Adapter in Visual Studio locally and I can run all the tests that way from Test Explorer so it's odd to me.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Why are you running an old build agent?

Comment: We have not been in a position yet to upgrade TFS Build to 2013.  Do you feel that would fix the issue?

Comment: Sorry, to have no proper answer. All I can tell you is that we also use that download with TFS 2012 (Build) and have no such issue. It might be something related to your build machine, maybe.